# KQL sentinel - query a user log on/off activity for the month

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm new to KQL and I'm trying to pull user sign in data for the month, currently this is the query I've used to pull data for a specific day. How can I get all the sign in/off times for the month, I imagine the summarize operator is my problem as its grouping the rest of the data I need but unsure on the best way to go about retrieving it.

```
SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(30d))
| where TimeGenerated < endofday(ago(15h))
| where EventID in (4624, 4625, 4634)
| where TargetUserName contains "Johnsmith"
| summarize StartTime = min(TimeGenerated), EndTimec = max(TimeGenerated), count() by LogonTypeName, Account, Activity
| extend timestamp = StartTime
| extend timestamp = EndTimec
```

Here is the results from the above query with the account column removed.

| LogonTypeName | Activity | StartTime [UTC] | EndTimec [UTC] | count_ | timestamp [UTC] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 - Network | 4624 - An account was successfully logged on. | 1/10/2023, 7:57:19.026 AM | 1/10/2023, 3:57:34.764 PM | 208 | 1/10/2023, 3:57:34.764 PM |
| 3 - Network | 4634 - An account was logged off. | 1/10/2023, 7:57:19.066 AM | 1/10/2023, 3:57:34.831 PM | 208 | 1/10/2023, 3:57:34.831 PM |

I'm trying to pull user data of the time they sign in and sign off everyday that month for auditing purposes. The issue is the above query is only returning yesterday times and not the other 29 days of the month.

Apologies if the formatting for this question isn't perfect.

Comment: Not much to do with this question without familiarity with your data. The best approach would be to share a sample' data + required results (as CSV / datatable). Please make sure that you are not sharing a sensitive data.

Comment: No. If your query would have returned the required result, you would not post a question in StackOverflow. You should post the raw data and the required results (use CSV or datatable  as I requested and avoid images) and give a few words on the transformation logic between the two.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: I have updated the post to include the datatable that the above query produces.

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly you are looking for. Please share sample of the raw data (original records of SecurityEvent) + required results.